# Theorem 3.1 in Erwin Kreyszig's "Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications": Is the notion of convex set valid in complex vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Is the notion of convex sets valid and meaningful for complex vector spaces?

Or, do we need to restrict ourselves to real vector spaces and normed spaces when we talk about convex sets?

The definition of the convex set perfectly makes sense in the complex case also, but its geometric interpretation (i.e. the one involving the concept of a segment) is lost, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of a line segment is not lost in a complex vector space.

If $u,v \in V$, a complex vector space, then $(1-\lambda) u + \lambda v \in V$ for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$. The set $$\{ (1-\lambda)u + \lambda v : \lambda \in [0,1]\}$$ is a line segment in this space. All the operations are well defined for complex or real vector spaces.

For instance, if we take the one dimensional vectors space $\mathbb{C}$, then for any $u, v \in \mathbb{C}$, the line segment connecting the point $u$ to the point $v$ can be drawn on the complex plane as a line in the standard sense.